# How to view my running docker image in the browser via private IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I'm running my docker image in my docker container in my AWS EC2 instance inside my virtual Ubuntu machine and am trying to access it via my virtual Ubuntu machine. I understand that typically one would view the running image using their public DNS in the web browser, but I'm logged into my EC2 instance via my private IP (not my public DNS). Therefore, I'm unable to view my running image via my public DNS.

I've tried my private IP, my private IP:8080 (since docker ps shows 8080/tcp for this image), and my public IP & DNS in the browser. Is the private DNS the answer? If so, how would I go about making it a valid URL?

If I haven't provided enough info, just let me know and I'll be sure to do so. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can first verify if your container is up by using `docker ps` then check `netstat -nptel` on host to see if the application is listening on 8080. Also verify by using `curl localhost:8080` on host to see if container is serving the requests.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing terms like image, container... a little bit – maybe you should read up on that (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/).

> An image is an executable package that includes everything needed to run an application--the code, a runtime, libraries, environment variables, and configuration files.
>
> A container is a runtime instance of an image--what the image becomes in memory when executed (that is, an image with state, or a user process).

If you want to access the containers from the docker host on which they're running, have you tried `localhost`?
So something like:

`curl http://localhost:8080/`

If it only shows `8080/tcp`, this most likely means that you first need to publish the port by adding the `-p` flag to the docker run command (https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/):

`docker run -p 8080:8080 ... image-name`